# In drupal 10, Can i use devel generate module for ecommerce site?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I have content type with fields Product ID, Name, Image, description, category ( taxonomy ), price.
Can i Create sample products and select the respective sub categories with devel generate module ?

Answer (score 1):

Default devel module will not provide such facility, below mentioned module might help to achieve your requirements.

**Devel Generate Commerce:**
https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_generate_commerce